# Establish independent server session for an ajax request?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, session

I have a set of PHP server side scripts that maintain user session state using PHP sessions extensively throughout for a logged in user.

Client side in a mobile app, via Jquery ajax, I need to establish an independent session (authenticated as a different user) that does not disrupt the already established session.  In other words, to the server it must look like a different browser session.

Is there a way to programmatically accomplish this with Jquery/Javascript client side for only a specific request?

Comment: Are you using any kind of framework on PHP side.

Comment: I'm using a PHP login script framework - hybridauth which can be found at http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/ or a github fork at https://github.com/smarcombes/HybridAuth.  I'm successfully using the framework to log my user in, but the problem is I also want to use the framework to get other Social provider data for that user without logging them off the current session.  I don't want to create another instance/install of hybridauth on another domain/server just to keep sessions separate.  There has to be a way to allow for subordinate calls without logging the user out of the primary session.

Comment: In the mobile app, what other user is getting authenticated? Does the USER send the credentials or is it built into the Client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sessions in PHP are transmitted using an identifier, which is generally passed as a cookie -- see the [**Passing the Session ID**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php) section of the manual.

This means that if that identifier *(cookie)* is not passed to the Ajax query, then, the PHP script called via that query will not consider that the user is the same ; and will see him as a different one.

So, basically : you must find a way to not pass that session identifier, when doing your Ajax request.

Of course : don't delete the cookie : it must remain here, for the other kind of requests, if you don't want your use to lose his session.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, but it probably would be better to use a different server/domain that doesn't share session information with the original server/domain.